# In the Google Play Developer console, I'm getting warnings in the Pre-Launch tests mentioning:

Tags: android

In the **Google Play Developer console**, I'm getting warnings in the Pre-Launch tests mentioning:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field java.lang.String android.accounts.Account.type on a null object reference

The app never crashes and the test succeeds, but the warning is still there in details of the test. What is `android.accounts.Account` and how can I make sure it doesn't have issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Account Manager, Make sure you are passing two arguments.

```
final Account account = new Account(mUsername, your_account_type);
mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, mPassword, null);
```

For more - [Android documentation for Account Manager](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html#Security)

If you are not using Account Manager, just ignore. And give more details about what feature you are adding.